# Can one corrupt git repo corrupt another?

Tags: git

I've just recovered from a corrupt repo situation and now I'm trying to understand what might have caused it.

Set up:

- central bare Git repo: this server had its power cut (accident). This could have caused corruption on disk (it's a btrfs fs and a 'scrub' operation says it's clean, but feasibly it died in the middle of a Git operation?)
- local dev VM: I'm not aware of this having been treated badly, but there's a thin possibility I suppose of something going wrong. I had been happily working on it all day, including making commits, without any problems.

I noticed the error when I tried to do a `git push` from my local dev to the central repo. I think when I saw an error I might have done a `git pull` (usually when there's an error pushing it's because you need to pull first, so I may have done this instinctively). That's when the errors started.

The central repo was clearly corrupt: `git fsck` just segfaulted! But it also seemed to have corrupted my local repo quite badly. Locally, I could run `fsck` which reported some dangling commits, but otherwise did not error. But then trying any other operations reported empty files in the `.git` dir and stopped. Deleting those then gave a load of more serious looking errors.

In the end I repaired by getting a known-good backup of the central repo; cloning that; moving the cloned `.git` dir in place of my local broken one; committing my work tree on top of the old commit (so I lost my separate commits but not my end-code); pushing.

I realise that I've not included any detailed errors, and that's not the point of the question.

My question is: **is it possible that pulling/fetching from a broken remote repo could corrupt my local repo?**

I had always assumed not, but it seems unlikely that 2 repos on different machines got corrupted at the same time.

Comment: From what I have heard, at least in the past, btrfs has not been very reliable in the face of power cuts and stuff like that. Nevertheless, Git should not segfault no matter what, so please send your report to the Git mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: is it possible that pulling/fetching from a broken remote repo could corrupt my local repo?

Yes.  If there are things that aren't being checked—and the fact that you had `git fsck` segfault suggests that there are—then the fetch step copying data into your local repository can copy something that isn't being checked.

In general, this indicates a bug in Git, because it's *supposed* to check *everything* in `git fsck`, and not segfault. :-)  Some kinds of less-obvious problems, such as invalid tree or tag entries, might escape the more-casual checking that `git fetch` runs, but if you can save the corrupt repository somewhere and allow Git developers to access it, they may be able to pinpoint the problem and prevent it from recurring in the future.